# Efficient Algorithm to solve maze gathering coins

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, maze

What is the best algorithm to use to solve a maze, which is ideally a graph, while gathering the most number of coins in a fixed number of steps?

Each edge has a distance and each node has a certain number of coins(0 - n coins)

The total fixed number of steps is given as input and it is guaranteed that there is a solution which solves the maze after these steps.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is a [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with weighted graph and without return

Comment: but trabeling salesman visits all nodes the sortest. I dont necessarily need to visit all nodes

Comment: There is a variation that involves cost constraint too (e.g. https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/6223080)

Comment: Otherwise, if it is related to game development, you can try asking that in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can use A* search algorithm

Comment: @SahilDhoked a* finds the shortest path but can’t find the second shortest if the first was too many steps right?

Comment: @yasgur99 Why do you need to find the second shortest path? You need the shortest path with the most number of coins, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the number of vertices in the graph?

Comment: @VineethChitteti correct me if i’m wrong but a* gives the optimal path. what happens if the optimal path (coin wise) is too many steps, then i need another path

Comment: @yasgur99 not if you use a proper heuristic. A* can do much more. Let's say you use your heuristic as #coins - #steps, then A* does a pretty neat job imo

Comment: Actually A* does more than that. A* uses f(n) = g(n) + h(n), where g(n) is the path taken and h(n) is the heuristic for the future path. So it automatically reduces the size of the path if you use h(n) = #coinsRemaining

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, you will not find an **efficient** solution for this problem, it is **NP-hard**, which means if you want a precise solution, it will have exponential complexity. This can be shown by reducing the [Knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem to it.

Assume you have an instance of Knapsack with **n** items, set **w_0...w_n** of weights and set **v_0..._v_n** of values, and capacity **W**, we can build a graph where each vertex corresponds to a value, plus 2 additional vertices **s** and **e** for start and end. Create an edge from **s** to each vertex **v_i** with weight **w_i/2**, and also an edge from **v_i** to the vertex **e** with corresponding weight **w_i/2**. Now find the path from **s** to **e**, limited to length **W**. This path will not visit vertex **v_i** more then once since after the coin is collected no reason to return to that node. Also, to visit any **v_i** and getting to **e** it will spend exactly **w_i** steps, whether if going from s or returning from e. The solution guarantees that the limit of steps is not exceeded and the combination of values is maximal. So by just picking all vertices **v_i** visited we have a solution to the optimization version of Knapsack which is NP-hard.

Now it is not all that bad. The problem has a solution, it is just inefficient. For a small maze, it may still work using brute force, i.e. start with a vertex and try to go in any direction recursively. If exceeded maximum number of steps - abort. If reached destination - return the path. Then of all the returned paths select the one that yields maximum coins.

Additionally, if you do not need a precise solution - you may try to give an approximate solution. For example, you can use [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm to produce shortest path tree. So now you have a shortest path from source to each vertex. Pick the path from source to destination, and try to improve it iteratively. In each iteration pick a vertex on the path, look at all its neighbors and see it going through this neighbor gives you better value while still under steps constraint. This will not necessarily give you the optimal solution, but will likely produce some good solutions.

And then you can try other optimizations, like "pick a coin and run". Look at your path and try to improve it by going from some vertex to its neighbor and return immediately. It may be useful if your maze has a dead end, so that naturally you would not go there to reach destination, but you do have enough steps to go there collect some coins and return.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Alternative proof: set max-steps = num-nodes, and give each node 1 coin. Now you can trivially reduce from traveling salesman or hamiltonian path.